# How to access elements of the return value of mysql_fetch_array?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$con = mysql_connect("servername","username","password");
        if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
            mysql_select_db("Appiness", $con);

    $result= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM country");
    while($answer= mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo $answer;
    }
```

When i write this it gives me my array of 194 elements but when i echo them it only writes
ArrayArrayArray....... 194 times any idea why it is not giving the names of the countries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify which column you want out of your `$answer`-array.
If the column name is name:

```
echo $answer["name"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
while($answer= mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo implode("\t", $answer) . "\n";
}
```

to get all fields, or

```
while($answer= mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "$answer[0]\n";
}
```

to get the first field, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the filed that you want to display. mysql_fetch_array returns an array whose key values are the field names from the queried table and whose values are the values in that table for that row.